# JQuery $.ajax() with async to get data into variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I'm trying to get some data into a variable to use in a template. I've used `<?php file_get_contents(...)` in a file called `get.php` as a proxy to avoid cross-origin issue.

The code below works, but gives a warning that `'async' : false` is deprecated. However when I change it to `true` it returns null.

What am I missing please? What is the correct, modern approach to achieving what I'm trying to do?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var json = (function () {
    var json = null;
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': 'get.php',
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) {
            json = data;
        }
    });
    return json;
})(); 

console.log(json);

});
```

Comment: Try putting `console.log(json);` inside `success` and read about why use **async with ajax**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2):

## Problem

jQuery's `$.ajax()` is an asynchronous call, and the result is that `console.log()` is running *before* you finished retrieving the data.

## Solution

`$.ajax` returns a [jqXHR](http://devdocs.io/jquery/jquery.ajax#jqXHR) object. We'll use the `.done()` method of this object to finish out the async call. Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var def = $ajax({
        global: false,
        url: 'get.php',
        dataType: 'json'
    });

    // Pass in the completion callback here
    def.done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

The `.done()` method will be called when the AJAX call has completed and log out the JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `console.log(json);` is running before your `success` callback. If you move to immediately after `json = data;` it would work with `'async' : true`.

Comment: The thing is I need the `json` variable to be available to use in an HTML page with the script included. This works with the synchronous version. How can I achieve this please? Can my code be tweaked to make this happen or is the approach flawed?

Comment: You ought to read up, starting with the linked duplicate question in the comment from @aspillers. But one approach would be, wherever the code is that depends on `json`, ensure that code is in a `function` with a parameter called `json` (e.g. `function foo (json) { // code using json }`) and then replace the `success` callback with `'success': foo`.